# protobuf-net: What is an efficient way to transfer any type, defaulting to .NET serialization for unknown types?

Tags: protobuf-net

I have the following code, attempting to de/serialize an "Attribute" class, which is basically a name/value pair where the type of the value is unknown (object):

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(ValueAttr))]
public abstract class BaseAttr
{
    protected BaseAttr(string name) { _name = name; }
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public abstract object Value { get; }
    public abstract ValueAttr Evaluate();
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private readonly string _name;
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class ValueAttr : BaseAttr
{
    public ValueAttr(string name, object value) : base(name)
    { _value = value; }

    public override ValueAttr Evaluate() { return this; }

    public override object Value { get { return _value; } }
    [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
    protected object _value;
}

[Serializable]
public class Attr<T> : ValueAttr
{
    public Attr(string name, T value) : base(name, value) { _value = value; }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is protobuf-net "native" serialization for the native .NET types, and to default to binary .NET serialization for all other types (assuming they're Serializable, of course). I thought `DynamicType`can help me with that, until I found out that the "Dynamic" part refers only to contracted types.

What is the most efficient way (in time and memory) to do this? Is it using the [ValueWrapper](https://github.com/mdavid/protobuf-net/blob/master/Examples/ValueWrapper.cs) example in protobuf.net? If so, how do I implement the defualt .NET serialization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf-net doesn't have any code in it that would switch to `BinaryFormatter` (although it does have some code to allow itself to be used by `BinaryFormatter`). But if this is the root object, you should be able to ask the model itself when you serialize:

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
if (model.CanSerialize(type))
{
    // TODO: add some kind of token to indicate serializer used
    model.Serialize(dest, obj);
}
else if(type.IsSerializable)
{
    // TODO: add some kind of token to indicate serializer used
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(dest, obj);
}
else { /* PANIC!!!! */ }
```

This won't help you for child objects; ultimately, protobuf-net wants to understand the model.